# What should I study to understand basics of aircraft construction?

Tags: aircraft-design

I'm trying to undestand principles of construction of fixed-wing subsonic aircraft.

I have already read explanation on things such as Neutral Point, Static Margin, etc, but I'd like to know how they are linked together, what are typical values they have and why, what are pros and cons of different schemes, and so on. Some of this can be found here, but I think it would be more sound to learn basics first, and start looking for details afterwards.

A good example of literature (or Internet resource) I seek can be "The Jet Engine" book by Rolls Royce. It explains nature of processes while don't digging too much in formulas.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for putting this question on hold without any explanation what exactly is too broad and how can I correct it. Glad there is one who found few minutes to advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen many universities that they suggest [Anderson's Introduction to Flight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073380245) for the first course in aerospace engineering. This book contains fundamental aspects of the aeronautics.

Regarding construction principles, a good knowledge of aerodynamic, propulsion, structure and flight dynamics is required before getting into aircraft design. Meanwhile, as the first step you can familiarize yourself with the anatomy of the airplane with [Stinton's Anatomy of the Aeroplane](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0632018763), and then going to aircraft design books such as [Roskam's Airplane Design Books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1884885241) or [Torenbeek's Design book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9024727243).

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. It seems exactly what I need!